# How does getInvoiceCollection() work with orderCollectionFactory in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, collection, invoice, factory

The following code works but how can we identify what methods can be called on the order collection result, such as getInvoiceCollection?

```
$collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', $processingStatus)
        ->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');
    $orders = $collection->getItems();

    foreach($orders as $order){

        foreach($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $_invoice){
            $invoices[] = $_invoice;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the core order [file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1693) you can find the same file in your directory from below path

```
<your magento dir>/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php
```

Once you load the Order object you can call any function from the above file so when you invoke `$order->getInvoiceCollection()`

It simples loads the Invoice collection and filters the invoice for that particular order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE that supports type hints for variables you could use something like the following (PhpStorm example).

```
    $collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
                                               ->addFieldToFilter('status', $processingStatus)
                                               ->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');
    $orders = $collection->getItems();

    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    foreach($orders as $order){

        foreach($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $_invoice){
            $invoices[] = $_invoice;
        }

    }
```

which will then resolve the class hint for you like this:

[image: getInvoiceCollection() type hint]